# How to solve flutter project compile Debug Kotlin error

Tags: flutter, dart, gradle-plugin, flutter-packages, flutter-debug

I'm new to flutter development. I used audioplayers: ^0.19.0 package in one project but when the project runs on an emulator it pops up with big error messages. Can you guys please help me to solve this? I have no idea about is it my code error or a package problem.

Execution failed for task ':audioplayers:compileDebugKotlin'.

> Compilation error. See log for more details

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:audioplayers/audioplayers.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatefulWidget {
  const MyApp({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  _MyAppState createState() => _MyAppState();
}

class _MyAppState extends State<MyApp> {
 

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      home: Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(
          title: Text('Simple Music'),
          backgroundColor: Colors.amber[300],
        ),
        body: SafeArea(
          child: Center(
            child: TextButton(
              child: Text("music"),
              onPressed: () {
                final player = AudioCache();
                player.play("note2.wav");
              },
            ),
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Debug Console

```
Launching lib\main.dart on AOSP on IA Emulator in debug mode...
e: Incompatible classes were found in dependencies. Remove them from the classpath or use '-Xskip-metadata-version-check' to suppress errors
e: C:/Users/acer/.gradle/caches/transforms-2/files-2.1/24fa3aa8d2270e5eb067bbe36e9b7563/jetified-kotlin-stdlib-1.5.10.jar!/META-INF/kotlin-stdlib.kotlin_module: Module was compiled with an incompatible version of Kotlin. The binary version of its metadata is 1.5.1, expected version is 1.1.15.
e: C:/Users/acer/.gradle/caches/transforms-2/files-2.1/4d4ccf1034ba5937e6e7ba3aa34d2661/jetified-core-ktx-1.6.0-beta02-api.jar!/META-INF/core-ktx_release.kotlin_module: Module was compiled with an incompatible version of Kotlin. The binary version of its metadata is 1.5.1, expected version is 1.1.15.
e: C:/Users/acer/.gradle/caches/transforms-2/files-2.1/77bab1911042ab2c6d5cc0b2e2ee053c/jetified-kotlin-stdlib-common-1.5.10.jar!/META-INF/kotlin-stdlib-common.kotlin_module: Module was compiled with an incompatible version of Kotlin. The binary version of its metadata is 1.5.1, expected version is 1.1.15.
e: C:\Flutter\Flutter\Flutter_sdk\.pub-cache\hosted\pub.dartlang.org\audioplayers-0.19.0\android\src\main\kotlin\xyz\luan\audioplayers\AudioplayersPlugin.kt: (18, 32): Unresolved reference: mutableMapOf
e: C:\Flutter\Flutter\Flutter_sdk\.pub-cache\hosted\pub.dartlang.org\audioplayers-0.19.0\android\src\main\kotlin\xyz\luan\audioplayers\AudioplayersPlugin.kt: (25, 9): Class 'kotlin.Unit' was compiled with an incompatible version of Kotlin. The binary version of its metadata is 1.5.1, expected version is 1.1.15.
The class is loaded from C:/Users/acer/.gradle/caches/transforms-2/files-2.1/24fa3aa8d2270e5eb067bbe36e9b7563/jetified-kotlin-stdlib-1.5.10.jar!/kotlin/Unit.class
e: C:\Flutter\Flutter\Flutter_sdk\.pub-cache\hosted\pub.dartlang.org\audioplayers-0.19.0\android\src\main\kotlin\xyz\luan\audioplayers\AudioplayersPlugin.kt: (26, 9): Class 'kotlin.Unit' was compiled with an incompatible version of Kotlin. The binary version of its metadata is 1.5.1, expected version is 1.1.15.
The class is loaded from C:/Users/acer/.gradle/caches/transforms-2/files-2.1/24fa3aa8d2270e5eb067bbe36e9b7563/jetified-kotlin-stdlib-1.5.10.jar!/kotlin/Unit.class
e: C:\Flutter\Flutter\Flutter_sdk\.pub-cache\hosted\pub.dartlang.org\audioplayers-0.19.0\android\src\main\kotlin\xyz\luan\audioplayers\AudioplayersPlugin.kt: (27, 9): Class 'kotlin.Unit' was compiled with an incompatible version of Kotlin. The binary version of its metadata is 1.5.1, expected version is 1.1.15.
The class is loaded from C:/Users/acer/.gradle/caches/transforms-2/files-2.1/24fa3aa8d2270e5eb067bbe36e9b7563/jetified-kotlin-stdlib-1.5.10.jar!/kotlin/Unit.class
e: C:\Flutter\Flutter\Flutter_sdk\.pub-cache\hosted\pub.dartlang.org\audioplayers-0.19.0\android\src\main\kotlin\xyz\luan\audioplayers\AudioplayersPlugin.kt: (28, 17): Class 'kotlin.Unit' was compiled with an incompatible version of Kotlin. The binary version of its metadata is 1.5.1, expected version is 1.1.15.
The class is loaded from C:/Users/acer/.gradle/caches/transforms-2/files-2.1/24fa3aa8d2270e5eb067bbe36e9b7563/jetified-kotlin-stdlib-1.5.10.jar!/kotlin/Unit.class

e: C:\Flutter\Flutter\Flutter_sdk\.pub-cache\hosted\pub.dartlang.org\audioplayers-0.19.0\android\src\main\kotlin\xyz\luan\audioplayers\WrappedSoundPool.kt: (127, 13): Class 'kotlin.Unit' was compiled with an incompatible version of Kotlin. The binary version of its metadata is 1.5.1, expected version is 1.1.15.
The class is loaded from C:/Users/acer/.gradle/caches/transforms-2/files-2.1/24fa3aa8d2270e5eb067bbe36e9b7563/jetified-kotlin-stdlib-1.5.10.jar!/kotlin/Unit.class
e: C:\Flutter\Flutter\Flutter_sdk\.pub-cache\hosted\pub.dartlang.org\audioplayers-0.19.0\android\src\main\kotlin\xyz\luan\audioplayers\WrappedSoundPool.kt: (129, 9): Unresolved reference: synchronized

e: C:\Flutter\Flutter\Flutter_sdk\.pub-cache\hosted\pub.dartlang.org\audioplayers-0.19.0\android\src\main\kotlin\xyz\luan\audioplayers\WrappedSoundPool.kt: (130, 18): Class 'kotlin.Unit' was compiled with an incompatible version of Kotlin. The binary version of its metadata is 1.5.1, expected version is 1.1.15.
The class is loaded from C:/Users/acer/.gradle/caches/transforms-2/files-2.1/24fa3aa8d2270e5eb067bbe36e9b7563/jetified-kotlin-stdlib-1.5.10.jar!/kotlin/Unit.class
e: C:\Flutter\Flutter\Flutter_sdk\.pub-cache\hosted\pub.dartlang.org\audioplayers-0.19.0\android\src\main\kotlin\xyz\luan\audioplayers\WrappedSoundPool.kt: (131, 59): Unresolved reference: mutableListOf

e: C:\Flutter\Flutter\Flutter_sdk\.pub-cache\hosted\pub.dartlang.org\audioplayers-0.19.0\android\src\main\kotlin\xyz\luan\audioplayers\WrappedSoundPool.kt: (136, 17): Class 'kotlin.Unit' was compiled with an incompatible version of Kotlin. The binary version of its metadata is 1.5.1, expected version is 1.1.15.
The class is loaded from C:/Users/acer/.gradle/caches/transforms-2/files-2.1/24fa3aa8d2270e5eb067bbe36e9b7563/jetified-kotlin-stdlib-1.5.10.jar!/kotlin/Unit.class
e: C:\Flutter\Flutter\Flutter_sdk\.pub-cache\hosted\pub.dartlang.org\audioplayers-0.19.0\android\src\main\kotlin\xyz\luan\audioplayers\WrappedSoundPool.kt: (137, 17): Class 'kotlin.Unit' was compiled with an incompatible version of Kotlin. The binary version of its metadata is 1.5.1, expected version is 1.1.15.

The class is loaded from C:/Users/acer/.gradle/caches/transforms-2/files-2.1/24fa3aa8d2270e5eb067bbe36e9b7563/jetified-kotlin-stdlib-1.5.10.jar!/kotlin/Unit.class
e: C:\Flutter\Flutter\Flutter_sdk\.pub-cache\hosted\pub.dartlang.org\audioplayers-0.19.0\android\src\main\kotlin\xyz\luan\audioplayers\WrappedSoundPool.kt: (143, 17): Class 'kotlin.Unit' was compiled with an incompatible version of Kotlin. The binary version of its metadata is 1.5.1, expected version is 1.1.15.
The class is loaded from C:/Users/acer/.gradle/caches/transforms-2/files-2.1/24fa3aa8d2270e5eb067bbe36e9b7563/jetified-kotlin-stdlib-1.5.10.jar!/kotlin/Unit.class

e: C:\Flutter\Flutter\Flutter_sdk\.pub-cache\hosted\pub.dartlang.org\audioplayers-0.19.0\android\src\main\kotlin\xyz\luan\audioplayers\WrappedSoundPool.kt: (144, 17): Class 'kotlin.Unit' was compiled with an incompatible version of Kotlin. The binary version of its metadata is 1.5.1, expected version is 1.1.15.
The class is loaded from C:/Users/acer/.gradle/caches/transforms-2/files-2.1/24fa3aa8d2270e5eb067bbe36e9b7563/jetified-kotlin-stdlib-1.5.10.jar!/kotlin/Unit.class
e: C:\Flutter\Flutter\Flutter_sdk\.pub-cache\hosted\pub.dartlang.org\audioplayers-0.19.0\android\src\main\kotlin\xyz\luan\audioplayers\WrappedSoundPool.kt: (154, 14): Class 'kotlin.Unit' was compiled with an incompatible version of Kotlin. The binary version of its metadata is 1.5.1, expected version is 1.1.15.

The class is loaded from C:/Users/acer/.gradle/caches/transforms-2/files-2.1/24fa3aa8d2270e5eb067bbe36e9b7563/jetified-kotlin-stdlib-1.5.10.jar!/kotlin/Unit.class
e: C:\Flutter\Flutter\Flutter_sdk\.pub-cache\hosted\pub.dartlang.org\audioplayers-0.19.0\android\src\main\kotlin\xyz\luan\audioplayers\WrappedSoundPool.kt: (156, 23): Unresolved reference: let
e: C:\Flutter\Flutter\Flutter_sdk\.pub-cache\hosted\pub.dartlang.org\audioplayers-0.19.0\android\src\main\kotlin\xyz\luan\audioplayers\WrappedSoundPool.kt: (156, 39): Class 'kotlin.Unit' was compiled with an incompatible version of Kotlin. The binary version of its metadata is 1.5.1, expected version is 1.1.15.

The class is loaded from C:/Users/acer/.gradle/caches/transforms-2/files-2.1/24fa3aa8d2270e5eb067bbe36e9b7563/jetified-kotlin-stdlib-1.5.10.jar!/kotlin/Unit.class
e: C:\Flutter\Flutter\Flutter_sdk\.pub-cache\hosted\pub.dartlang.org\audioplayers-0.19.0\android\src\main\kotlin\xyz\luan\audioplayers\WrappedSoundPool.kt: (156, 49): Unresolved reference: it
e: C:\Flutter\Flutter\Flutter_sdk\.pub-cache\hosted\pub.dartlang.org\audioplayers-0.19.0\android\src\main\kotlin\xyz\luan\audioplayers\WrappedSoundPool.kt: (161, 14): Class 'kotlin.Unit' was compiled with an incompatible version of Kotlin. The binary version of its metadata is 1.5.1, expected version is 1.1.15.

The class is loaded from C:/Users/acer/.gradle/caches/transforms-2/files-2.1/24fa3aa8d2270e5eb067bbe36e9b7563/jetified-kotlin-stdlib-1.5.10.jar!/kotlin/Unit.class
e: C:\Flutter\Flutter\Flutter_sdk\.pub-cache\hosted\pub.dartlang.org\audioplayers-0.19.0\android\src\main\kotlin\xyz\luan\audioplayers\WrappedSoundPool.kt: (163, 23): Unresolved reference: let

e: C:\Flutter\Flutter\Flutter_sdk\.pub-cache\hosted\pub.dartlang.org\audioplayers-0.19.0\android\src\main\kotlin\xyz\luan\audioplayers\WrappedSoundPool.kt: (163, 39): Class 'kotlin.Unit' was compiled with an incompatible version of Kotlin. The binary version of its metadata is 1.5.1, expected version is 1.1.15.
The class is loaded from C:/Users/acer/.gradle/caches/transforms-2/files-2.1/24fa3aa8d2270e5eb067bbe36e9b7563/jetified-kotlin-stdlib-1.5.10.jar!/kotlin/Unit.class
e: C:\Flutter\Flutter\Flutter_sdk\.pub-cache\hosted\pub.dartlang.org\audioplayers-0.19.0\android\src\main\kotlin\xyz\luan\audioplayers\WrappedSoundPool.kt: (163, 47): Unresolved reference: it


e: C:\Flutter\Flutter\Flutter_sdk\.pub-cache\hosted\pub.dartlang.org\audioplayers-0.19.0\android\src\main\kotlin\xyz\luan\audioplayers\WrappedSoundPool.kt: (235, 30): Class 'kotlin.Unit' was compiled with an incompatible version of Kotlin. The binary version of its metadata is 1.5.1, expected version is 1.1.15.
The class is loaded from C:/Users/acer/.gradle/caches/transforms-2/files-2.1/24fa3aa8d2270e5eb067bbe36e9b7563/jetified-kotlin-stdlib-1.5.10.jar!/kotlin/Unit.class

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':audioplayers:compileDebugKotlin'.
> Compilation error. See log for more details

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 1m 50s

Exception: Gradle task assembleDebug failed with exit code 1
Exited (sigterm)
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try changing the ext.kotlin_version value in your build.gradle file (located in the android folder of your project) like so:

```
buildscript {
    ext.kotlin_version = '1.5.10'
    
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
    }

    dependencies{
        ...
    }
}
```